# Angular 2 RXJS observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I must be missing something super obvious here...

```
public suggestedData$: Observable<string[]>;
public suggestionStream = new Subject<string>();

nextSuggestion(){
    this.suggestionStream.next( this.query );
}

this.suggestionStream
    .map(query => {
        return this._someService.getSomeThings( query );
     });

this.suggestionData$ = this.suggestionStream.subscribe();
```

And then in the template I'd like to use the observable like this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestionData$ | async">{{suggestion.something}}</li>
</ul>
```

Visual studio is saying: `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string[]>'.` for `this.suggestionData$ = this.sug...`

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
this.suggestionStream
    .map(query => {
        console.log(query);
            return this._someService.getSomeThings(query);
        })
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log('res', res);
        });
```

Prints in the console:

`res Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`

_someService looks like this:

```
getSomeThings(query: string){

    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('query', query);

    return this.http.get('https://api.../suggest', {search: params})
        .map(res => res.json() || []);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.suggestionStream.subscribe()` is of type Subscription, not an Observable. So I think what you're trying to achieve would look like the following:

```
public suggestedData$: new Observable<string[]>;
public suggestionStream = new Subject<string>();

nextSuggestion(){
  this.suggestionStream.next( this.query );
}

this.suggestionData$ = this.suggestionStream
  .map(query => {
    return this._someService.getSomeValues( query );
  });
```

The async pipe will do the subscription.

Comment: That what I thought... I get this error in Visual Studio:
`Type 'Observable<Observable<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string[]>'.
  Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.` No error in the console, it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try flatMap operator instead of map. I also think suggestedData should be Observable<string>

Comment: try 'Observable<Observable<any[]>>'  -- just add inside th [] - its mean array of any